# RIA method does not appear in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a DomainService with a few methods.

One has a return type of string and no parameter:

```
public string MyMethod1() { }
```

I can call this one from Silverlight.

One has a return type of void, and a parameter that is a domain object (I am using LinqToSqlDomainService and this object is part of the DataContext):

```
public void MyMethod2(MyDomainObject object) { }
```

I can also call this one from Silverlight.

Another one has a return type of string and a parameter that is a domain object:

```
public string MyMethod3(MyDomainObject object) { }
```

I **cannot call this one from Silverlight**, as the method doesn't get generated on the proxy.

Why is it not generated and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `[Invoke]` attribute to the operation.

I created a sample application defined with the following contract and I was able to have all three methods generated in the Silverlight application.

Here is the DBML file.
[image: LINQ to SQL DBML file]

Here is the defined service.

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class DomainService1 : LinqToSqlDomainService<DataClasses1DataContext>
{
    public Player GetPlayer()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MyMethod(Player player)
    {
    }

    [Invoke]
    public string MyMethod2(Player player)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And this was the generated code in the Silverlight project:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets an EntityQuery instance that can be used to load <see cref="Player"/> entities using the 'GetPlayer' query.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>An EntityQuery that can be loaded to retrieve <see cref="Player"/> entities.</returns>
public EntityQuery<Player> GetPlayerQuery()
{
    this.ValidateMethod("GetPlayerQuery", null);
    return base.CreateQuery<Player>("GetPlayer", null, false, false);
}

/// <summary>
/// Invokes the 'MyMethod' method of the specified <see cref="Player"/> entity.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="player">The <see cref="Player"/> entity instance.</param>
public void MyMethod(Player player)
{
    player.MyMethod();
}

/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously invokes the 'MyMethod2' method of the domain service.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="player">The value for the 'player' parameter of this action.</param>
/// <param name="callback">Callback to invoke when the operation completes.</param>
/// <param name="userState">Value to pass to the callback.  It can be <c>null</c>.</param>
/// <returns>An operation instance that can be used to manage the asynchronous request.</returns>
public InvokeOperation<string> MyMethod2(Player player, Action<InvokeOperation<string>> callback, object userState)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("player", player);
    this.ValidateMethod("MyMethod2", parameters);
    return ((InvokeOperation<string>)(this.InvokeOperation("MyMethod2", typeof(string), parameters, true, callback, userState)));
}

/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously invokes the 'MyMethod2' method of the domain service.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="player">The value for the 'player' parameter of this action.</param>
/// <returns>An operation instance that can be used to manage the asynchronous request.</returns>
public InvokeOperation<string> MyMethod2(Player player)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("player", player);
    this.ValidateMethod("MyMethod2", parameters);
    return ((InvokeOperation<string>)(this.InvokeOperation("MyMethod2", typeof(string), parameters, true, null, null)));
}
```

Comment: "Operation named 'Method4' does not conform to the required signature. Parameter types must be an entity type or one of the predefined serializable types." - My type is defined in my LinqToSql classes (.dbml) file. It does not have an Entity attribute, just a TableAttribute.

Comment: Does your type have a Key defined?

Comment: The ID column is set to be the primary key in both the database and the LinqToSql designer. In the generated code the ID property is marked with `[ColumnAttribute(IsPrimaryKey=true)]`.

Comment: Updated my answer with a code sample.  I was able to get this working with only the [Invoke] attribute.  Maybe try to do what you're doing in a new "clean" project and see if you run into the same issue?

Comment: Ok, I got it now. It works, but only if there is a method in the service that returns the domain objects. So your example works thanks to the GetPlayer() method. If you take it out, it won't compile. The message is pretty clear on MyMethod (it says the type must be exposed by the service), but if you just leave MyMethod2 with the [Invoke], you'll get the message I posted before. Thanks for helping me clearing it up!